# The appearance of eclipse markers depend on the editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

**Is it possible to get the same maker appearance in both java and JavaScript editors in eclipse?**

In my eclipse plugin, I'm using customized Markers. As well as use the same code for setting markers, in both .java and .js editors. In the java editor markers are working fine,

```
String errorMsg = "This my test error message";
String fixMsg = "This is my test fix message";
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, errorMsg + "\n\n" + fixMsg);
```

The expectation is to set markers on JavaScript files same as on the java files. (With icon and customized text formatting).

[image: Java Editor]
[image: Java Script Editor]

Comment: Editors are free to display markers (and other annotations) anyway they like using interfaces such as `ITextHover` and its many extensions. So I think you will struggle with this requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here, as in, what should an Answer look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching with regard to this, The thing I realized was, eclipse still haven't this kind of feasibility, Adding customized icon, and formatted text in maker appearance, in some editors such as JavaScript editor.